# jQuery selection: traversing up, then back down

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I am struggling with how to select a particular element with jQuery. Conditions outlined here:

- At the relevant point in my function, `this` references a `span`.
- That `span` may be a child, grand child, or great grand child, but somewhere up the hierarchy, it's contained by a `td`.
- **I'd like to select the last `span` inside of the `td`.**
- The `span` may be `this`, or it may be another `span`.
- The `span` tags to be selected is a direct child of the containing `td`, so `last-child` is workable. However, for future flexibility a solution that doesn't assume it's a direct child is preferred.

So far, I am using this to select the correct parent element:

```
$(this).parents('td')
```

I don't know how to traverse back down the DOM tree to get the final `span` inside of the selected `td`. Thanks!

**Edit**

Per my comments below, would also be nice to select from a `span` or `div`, whichever is last.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$(this).parents('td').children('span:last');
```

should do the trick.

**Edit**

I didn't notice your desire to not only deal with immediate children. If you want all decendants, then you would use

```
$(this).parents('td').find('span:last')
```

I had assumed the `span` would always be a child of the `td`.

**Final Edit**

For posterity's sake (and to make it easier for people to find this answer in the future), since this was already accepted as the answer, Ben came up with a more elegant solution in his answer that I'm going to put here:

```
$(this).closest('td').find('div,span').filter(':last')
```

As Ben said, you must be using JQuery 1.3 for `closest()` to work. Good work! :-)

Comment: children() only searches immediate children.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer to use [closest](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/closest#expr) in this case, instead [parents](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/parents#expr). You don't have to worry about there being two or more 'td' elements in the ancestry.

```
$(this).closest('td').children("span:last")
```

Answer (score 4):

The function you're looking for is [find(expr)](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/find#expr), which searches all descendant nodes:

```
$(this).closest('td').find('span:last')
```

**Edit:** To select the last `div` or `span`:

```
$(this).closest('td').find('div,span').filter(':last')
```

**Edit 2:** [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916618/jquery-selection-traversing-up-then-back-down/916781#916781) makes an excellent point about using [closest()](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/closest#expr) instead of [parents()](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/parents#expr), but be aware that you need to be using jQuery 1.3 for it.

Comment: Thanks! Can we tweak a bit further? What if I wanted to find the last element, but instead of limiting to span, it could be a span or a div?

Comment: You can replace span with whatever element you'd like.

Comment: I'm talking about a span OR a div. Invalid syntax, but something like this:

$(this).parents('td').filter('input').find('div,span:last')

Comment: I'll append this to my answer. I didn't see that you mentioned selecting either a div or a span in your original question.

Comment: Actually, that syntax is valid. But if the span comes after the div, the div still gets selected. I'm trying to select a span or a div, whichever is last.

Comment: Oh. I'm not quite sure how to do that in a one-liner. Could do it with a few statements, though.

Comment: I can figure it out in a multi-liner. Thanks!